# How to get structure items in Delphi

Tags: delphi

today is my first day with Delphi.

I have record like this:

```
type 
  FT_Device_Info_Node = record
    Flags         : DWord;
    DeviceType    : Dword;
    ID            : DWord;
    LocID         : DWord;
    SerialNumber  : array [0..15] of Char;
    Description   : array [0..63] of Char;
    DeviceHandle  : DWord;
  end;
```

Later I can read only arrays, e.g. it works: `FT_DeviceInfoList[0].SerialNumber`
But I can't get access to any of DWord item, e.g. `FT_DeviceInfoList[0].ID` is impossible.

Could you clarify it for me?

EDIT:
Here is button click procedure where I want to fet info from record:

```
procedure TForm1.checkFTDIClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  ftStatus := FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(@dwNumDevs);
  SetLength(FT_DeviceInfoList,dwNumDevs);
  ftStatus :=  FT_GetDeviceInfoList(FT_DeviceInfoList, @dwNumDevs);
  If ftStatus <> FT_OK then ShowMessage('Error '+IntToStr(ftStatus));

  Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  for i:=0 to dwNumDevs-1 do
  begin
    Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].Description);//works
    //Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].ID);//compilation error
  end;
  Form1.ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;

end;
```

FT things are from FTDI library and returned status is OK.

Comment: You'll have to improve the question. There's no problem at all reading fields from a record. Please show a complete program that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The updated code doesn't read the `ID` field.

Comment: Sure. I pasted that what works. I'd like to replace `Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].Description);` with `Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].ID);`

Comment: That information needs to be in the question. I added it. Without that information it was impossible to work out what the problem was. Whenever you ask a question about a compilation error, always include the code that produces the error, and the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intended code is:

```
Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].ID);
```

This results in a compilation error. That's because `Add` expects a parameter of type `string`. But you are passing a `DWORD`, an integral parameter.

Convert it from an integral data type to a string by calling `IntToStr`:

```
Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(FT_DeviceInfoList[i].ID));
```

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for your responses to my comments.

Comment: I suspect that @bLazy may be a C++Builder user, because in C++Builder, a `DWORD` value can be passed directly to a `String` without needing to call `IntToStr()`, as both `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` are implemented as C++ classes that both have multiple constructors for various data types, including one that is compatible with `DWORD`.

Comment: I use old Borland Delphi 7. Yes, I know, I should find something contemporary. BTW maybe you know some good free IDE for Delphi?

Comment: To my BTW question: I see now, Delphi is IDE. There is only Starter free version now. Some people suggest Lazarus, but it is not the same.

Comment: There is no free Delphi IDE for modern Delphi's. There were Personal editions for older Delphi.